# Disable mouse drag on slider

Tags: wpf

In my WPF window, I have a button and a slider.

Fist of all, I drag the slider to a value say 5. Once I click the button, a parallel processes runs, which means 5 tasks are running. When a task is done then the value of the slider is decremented. When all tasks finishes, the valus of the slider should be 0.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
{
   slider.Value = slider.Value - 1;
}
```

However the issue is I still can play the slider with the mouse in the meantime. I can drag the slider to an arbitrary value when running. I want to disable the mouse drag function during the process.

Comment: disabling the slider should be the expected behavior. If you don't want the look and feel of the disabled state, just try using some style for that state, however I would recommend to keep that default behavior. When user cannot drag the tick bar, it should have some look and feel of disabled state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new value is selected, and you kick off the tasks, you should also disable the slider by setting `slider.IsEnabled = false`.  When your last task finishes, have it re-enable the slider.  The user will not be able to manipulate the slider in any way while it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the slider to look normal but not accept input, you can try setting both `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable` to `False`.

Comment: Making gui elements look editable while they are actually not is a rather questionable decision. All controls should signal wether they a modifiable by the user or not

Comment: @DenisSchaf It depends. You might want something to be disabled or you might wait it read-only. These are different. "Disabled" makes things hard to see and is no good if you want to preset the actual value, while "read only" does not have this problem. Slider does not support any "read only" (like textbox does for example), so this is a quick way to get something like this. And there's no problem in WPF to visualize this read only state with different styling.